# How to charge a particular card on a customer with Stripe.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

A customer object can have many cards in Stripe.com. How do you charge an existing card?

I've tried a few things, but the stripe api for some reason borks when to get an old customer token and a new card token instead of just creating a new card on that customer. So I've gone the route of retrieving all the customer's cards, then selecting one by radio button, then submitting the token of the chosen card into a charge

```
      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :amount => "#{@subscription.price}",
        :currency => "usd",
        :card => params[:existing_card_id],
        :description => "Subscription for #{current_user.email}"
      )
```

but I get the error

```
Stripe::InvalidRequestError: Invalid token id: card_24j3i2390s9df
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I figured this out.

With existing card tokens you have to send in the customer token as well

```
     charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :amount => "#{@subscription.price}",
        :currency => "usd",
        :customer => current_user.stripe_customer_id,
        :card => params[:existing_card_id],
        :description => "Subscription for #{current_user.email}"
      )
```

Comment: Thanks, this is not obvious in the docs, but this worked for me as well (PHP).

Comment: same here in python.  noticed you can also set source=existing_card_id instead of card=.

Comment: according to doc we must send :source => card_id https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#create_charge

Answer (score 9):

This answer help to ME apply the same solution in  PHP for charge an specific credit card customer, other than the default credit card. Here the pieces:

JSON:

```
{
  "charge": {
    "amount":122,
    "currency":"usd",
    "customer":"cus_7hVsgytCc79BL7",
    "card":"card_17SENFJ4sx1xVfmD8skoSjNs"
  }
}
```

PHP

```
    $item = $params->request->getJsonRawBody();
    $new_charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      "amount" => $this->ConvertAmount($item->charge->amount),
      "currency" => $item->charge->currency,
      "customer" => $item->charge->customer,
      "card" => $item->charge->card
    ));
    return $new_charge;
```